# PostgreSQL: How to find last user activity before inactive period, regardless of reengagement?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table recording timestamped user messages, and I need to find the last message sent by each user before he went inactive for 30 days or longer, even if said user reengaged later on. The output should only include one date per user, for the first time such a "dead window" occurred.

I thought about joining the table with itself, but I'm not sure which conditions I should be accounting for to get the correct messages.... any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function that you want is `lag()`.  The following gets you all such periods:

```
select m.*
from (select m.*, lag(sentdate) over (partition by user order by sentdate) as lastsentdate
      from messages m
     ) m
where lastsentdate < sentdate - 30;
```

For the first, you can use `distinct on` or `row_number()`.  I prefer the latter because it is standard SQL:

```
select m.*
from (select m.*, row_number() over (partition by user order by sentdate) as seqnum
      from (select m.*, lag(sentdate) over (partition by user order by sentdate) as lastsentdate
            from messages m
           ) m
      where lastsentdate < sentdate - 30
     ) m
where seqnum = 1;
```